# RabbitMQ configuration error while enabling plugin

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, openflow

I'm getting the below error while trying to enable the RabbitMQ plugin from command line

**Environment Variables**

- ERLANG_HOME : D:\Program Files\erl-23.0
- RABBITMQ_BASE : C:\RabbitMQ
- RABBITMQ_SERVER : D:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server
- Path : ;%RABBITMQ_HOME%\sbin;%ERLANG_HOME%\bin;

  D:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.8.5\sbin>rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management

> 21:59:52.931 [error] GenServer :net_kernel terminating
> ** (stop) {:could_not_start_server, :inet_gethost_native}
> (kernel) inet_gethost_native.erl:549: :inet_gethost_native.ensure_started/0
> (kernel) inet_gethost_native.erl:488: :inet_gethost_native.getit/2
> (kernel) inet.erl:1295: :inet.gethostbyname_tm_native/4
> (kernel) inet.erl:1246: :inet.getaddrs_tm/3
> (kernel) inet.erl:658: :inet.getaddr_tm/3
> (kernel) inet.erl:653: :inet.getaddr/3
> (kernel) inet_tcp_dist.erl:59: :inet_tcp_dist.gen_select/2
> (kernel) net_kernel.erl:1526: :net_kernel.select_mod/2 Last message: {:auto_connect, :rabbit@IMPC3065, {1,
> #Reference<0.2404837920.965345282.258286>}}
>
> 21:59:52.931 [error] Process #PID<0.103.0> on node
> :"rabbitmqcli-3560-rabbit@IMPC3065" raised an exception
> ** (ErlangError) Erlang error: :eacces
> erlang.erl:2272: :erlang.open_port({:spawn, 'inet_gethost 4 '}, [{:packet, 4}, :eof, :binary])
> (kernel) inet_gethost_native.erl:184: :inet_gethost_native.server_init/2
>
> 21:59:52.931 [error] GenServer :inet_gethost_native_sup terminating
> ** (stop) :eacces
> erlang.erl:2272: :erlang.open_port({:spawn, 'inet_gethost 4 '}, [{:packet, 4}, :eof, :binary])
> (kernel) inet_gethost_native.erl:184: :inet_gethost_native.server_init/2 Last message: {:EXIT,
> #PID<0.103.0>, {:eacces, [{:erlang, :open_port, [{:spawn, 'inet_gethost 4 '}, [{:packet, 4}, :eof, :binary]], [file:
> 'erlang.erl', line: 2 272]}, {:inet_gethost_native, :server_init, 2,
> [file: 'inet_gethost_native.erl', line: 184]}]}} "escript: exception
> error: undefined function 'Elixir.Inspect.BitString':inspect/2\n  in
> function  'Elixir.Inspect.Algebra':container_each/6
> (lib/inspect/algebr a.ex, line 384)\n  in call from
> 'Elixir.Inspect.Algebra':container_doc/6 (lib/inspect/algebra.ex, line
> 362)\n  in call from 'Elixir.Inspect.Algebra':container_e ach/6
> (lib/inspect/algebra.ex, line 384)\n  in call from
> 'Elixir.Inspect.Algebra':container_doc/6 (lib/inspect/algebra.ex, line
> 362)\n  in call from 'Elixir.Ins pect.Algebra':container_each/6
> (lib/inspect/algebra.ex, line 384)\n  in call from
> 'Elixir.Inspect.Algebra':container_doc/6 (lib/inspect/algebra.ex, line
> 362)\n  in call from 'Elixir.Inspect.Algebra':container_each/6
> (lib/inspect/algebra.ex, line 384)\n"

Comment: It seems that you're getting an `eaccess` when Erlang tries to start its `inet_gethost` program. Please check that the program exists, and that RabbitMQ has enough permissions to launch it.

Comment: Thanks, i'm new to this RabbitMQ. Please guide in detail to resolve this.

Comment: try running `erl -eval "io:format(\"~p\", [inet:gethostbyname(\"stackoverflow.com\")]),init:stop()."`, if it does not return the ips of stackoverflow, check your erlang installation (I'm not sure about how to do that in Windows, sorry)

Comment: did u manage to resolve this?